# Python - Date parser that could get all the dates from a specific string input

Tags: python, datetime, flask, date-parsing, string-to-datetime

Currently doing a task that has given to me which is partly related to machine learning. The task is to **parse a string input from the user into a date,** given that I could have 2 parameter for the function: **date_from** and **date_to;** something like the given example below.

Any classes/functions that could help or an idea on how to do it would be a big help to me.

```
2.a 8th of July -> 2018-07-08
2.b July to December -> 2018-07 to 2018-12
2.c July -> 2018-07
2.d July 1st -> 2018-07-01
2.e Last week -> 2018-08-02 (curr_date - 7days)
2.f next week -> 2018-08-16 (curr_date + 7days)
2.g today -> 2018-08-09
2.h tomorrow -> 2018-08-10
2.i next monday -> 2018-08-13
2.j last monday -> 2018-07-30
2.k next month -> 2018-09 (or curr_date + 30days)
2.l last month -> 2018-07 (or curr_date - 30days)
```

Currently I'm using Flask for the development and testing.

Answer (score 0):

Several modules which could help:

1. The `calendar` module (pre-installed) --> [Link for more information](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html)
2. The `datetime` module (also pre-installed) --> [Link for more information](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html)
3. The `dateutil` module (**not pre-installed**). However, installing it is easy using `pip` (`pip install dateutil`) --> [Link for more information](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/)

There's tons of functions and methods in the modules above which allow you to work with dates (and times).

As for the actual parsing of the strings, it's likely you'll have to check for words like 'to' and 'of' manually. However, for months (like 'July' and 'December'), you could use a `list` to store them and then calculate the difference in months using the indices.

Comment: Hi, can you give a sample code on how I'm going to parse those kind of input. For example 10th of August to **08-10-2018**. I just need an idea for me to get started. Thanks!